# How do I use Atom's linter-jshint when code is split up across multiple files?

Tags: gruntjs, atom-editor

I'm writing a single-page JavaScript application and I'm using Atom as my text-editor. (It's an Electron application, but that's besides the point.)

I'm also using the `linter-jshint` plugin for Atom. This is great, as it shows immediately in the text-editor when I make a typo in a variable, among other useful things.

Lately, my app has been getting very long. Naturally, I want to try and split it up across multiple files. After doing [some research on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707914/can-you-use-multiple-js-files-when-developing-a-complex-javascript-application), I've determined that I can use Grunt to automatically concatenate JavaScript files together. This is great because I don't have to refactor my code - I can just copy paste my existing functions into separate files. Easy!

However, once I do this, Atom fills up with warnings and errors from JSHint, because it can't find variables and functions that are located in the other files!

Now, I could just abandon the JHint plugin in Atom altogether and use the JSHint plugin for Grunt after the concatenation has already occured. But that sucks! I want the code that I'm going to be writing to be checked on the fly like a real IDE.

Is there a way to tell Atom/JSHint to assume that a bunch of JavaScript files will all be concatenated together? Or am I just approaching this problem completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your electron application with [Node Common Modules](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/modules.html), and use `require('./state.js');` within your application.

Although I don't use Atom, that should allow for it to understand how you're using your variables and functions in other files.

Also this should eliminate your need for concatenation as the single-page app will have all it's dependencies accounted for.